# How do I use custom marker icons with Gmap?

Tags: google-maps

I want to show markers like on this map here http://demo.symphonythemes.com/drupal7/bizreview/ which are obviously custom.

How do I go about this? I'm either searching for the wrong thing or something.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Implementing a functionality or a layout seen in a site, for which just a description of the feature, a screenshot, or a site URL is provided.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! I am sorry, but _I want to do the same thing done in this site_ questions are off-topic here.This question is also too broad that could be seen as programming question not related to Drupal.

Comment: Hi Pierre, apologies on a late reply.

I ended up going with IP Geolocation & Views Maps and it has worked tremendously thanks!

On the content type I used address field for the address, geofield (which used the address field to make a geo location) and then used that geo info for the map within IPGVM module. I used it on top of Leaflet as well for the first time so overall, huge success and it did everything I needed and more!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [IP Geolocation Views & Maps](https://www.drupal.org/project/ip_geoloc) module. Partial quote from its project page:

> Despite what the name may suggest, IP Geolocation Views & Maps (IPGV&M) is first and foremost a mapping engine.
>
> The module makes it very easy to create Views-based mapping solutions using the map renderer of your choice (**Google**, **OpenLayers** or **Leaflet**) with any location storage module of your choice, e.g.:
>
> - [Get Locations](http://drupal.org/project/getlocations),
> - [Geofield](http://drupal.org/project/geofield),
> - [Geolocation Field](http://drupal.org/project/geolocation)
> - [Location](http://drupal.org/project/location).
>
> This allows you to bring together modules and feature sets that without IPGV&M you would not be able to combine.
>
> Like beautiful animated [marker clustering on Google or Bing or Mapbox ...](http://drupal.org/project/leaflet_markercluster) any of various [map providers](http://drupal.org/project/leaflet_more_maps).
>
> But more importantly IPGV&M adds some features you won't find as conveniently packaged elsewhere.
>
> These include [marker differentiation based on field values or ranges](http://flink.com.au/ramblings/spruce-your-map-markers-font-icons) (2nd screenshot) with or without font icons, various centering options, super-imposing the current visitor's location, allowing multiple content types to be displayed on the same map, full screen button and mini-map inset (bottom screenshot), polygon support (Geofield), marker tags and tool tips and cross-highlighting of associated content on the page when markers are hovered (and vice versa).
>
> And the [Set my location](http://regionbound.com/coffee-prices-across-melbourne) block allows your visitors to locate themselves on the map, either automagically --via the Wifi/GPS device on their mobile-- or by typing an address or landmark, like "Eiffel tower" (bottom screenshot, upper left corner, click to enlarge).
>
> Follow this step-by-step tutorial to create a handy [store locator with proximity search, from a list of addresses in a spreadsheet](http://www.chenhuijing.com/blog/drupal-101-mapping-with-leaflet-and-ipgeoloc). You'll learn about the [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) and [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) modules too!
>
> Finally IPGV&M provides a set of visitor location retrieval technologies, both IP and HTML5-based, so that you can track where past visits came from and where current visitors are located, superimposing their moving positions as markers on your maps.

Head over to its (impressive) project page for even more information about it (it would be way too long to include a quote of it all here).